# BETWEEN (2): [IsBetween, Between] is not supported for Redis query derivation

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm a beginner at spring data redis and I'm currently using Redis database as part of my application. And I am trying to query for records between two dates.

Here is my Repository class.

```java
public interface TransactionStatsRepository extends CrudRepository<TransactionStats, String> {
    List<TransactionStats> findByCreatedAtBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

I've indexed the `createdAt` field in my Entity class.

```java
@RedisHash("TRANSACTION")
public class TransactionStats implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    private String status;

    @Indexed
    private Date createdAt;

//Getters and Setters
```

The data insertion is being done in a typical CrudRepository way using the `save()` method.

```java
    public void addNewTransaction(String status, String createdAt) throws ParseException {
        TransactionStats stats = new TransactionStats();
        stats.setStatus(status);
        stats.setCreatedAt(getStringToDate(createdAt));
        transactionStatsRepository.save(stats);
    }

    private Date getStringToDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + timeZoneOffset));
        return formatter.parse(dateString);
    }
```

Here is the service class method accessing the repo method

```
public List<TransactionStatsDTO> getForDuration(String startDuration, String endDuration) throws ParseException {
        Date startDate = getStringToDate(startDuration);
        Date endDate = getStringToDate(endDuration);
        List<TransactionStatsDTO> transactionStatsDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        transactionStatsRepository.findByCreatedAtBetween(startDate, endDate)
                .forEach(transactionStats -> transactionStatsDTOs.add(mapper.map(transactionStats, TransactionStatsDTO.class)));
        return transactionStatsDTOs;
    }
```

But the repo method `findByCreatedAtBetween`when accessed is throwing the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BETWEEN (2): [IsBetween, Between] is not supported for Redis query derivation!
    at org.springframework.data.redis.repository.query.RedisQueryCreator.from(RedisQueryCreator.java:73) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.repository.query.RedisQueryCreator.create(RedisQueryCreator.java:53) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.repository.query.RedisQueryCreator.create(RedisQueryCreator.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.createQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:212) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.prepareQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:149) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.execute(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:107) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.findByCreatedAtBetween(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

Since Redis doesn't allow querying data in range as I've done, is there a way to retrieve the data in a date range?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Redis does currently (version 2.6.4 at the time of writing) not support Between queries. A list of supported keywords can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.queries).

To query the data in a range you could use a [sorted set](https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/#sorted-sets) with the zrangebyscore command, where the createdAt would be your score. To make the createdAt dates sortable and working with a sorted set, you should use the UNIX timestamp.

Here are the code snippets to add an entry to a sorted set and search for entries between two values:

```
// add a transaction entry to a sorted set which contains the id and the createdAt time
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add("TransactionCreationList", id, createdAt));
// search for transactions between a time range
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rangeByScoreWithScores("TransactionCreationList", startDate, endDate);
```